# History.replaceState() gives a 404 errorin the console

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

I want to change the url to `www.mysite.com/home` when the user visits my site's root folder(www.mysite.com).

I am using History.js to achieve this and I am using this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    History.replaceState({state: 'home'}, 'home', '/home');
});
```

with this piece of code I get a 404 error in the console indicating that www.mysite.com/home does not exist(which isn't).
Why am I getting this problem? since I came to believe that history's apis won't actually load the real resources.

ps: the page works ok, but I don't want to receive this error in the console, what should I do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem here is that you don't currently have a state to replace when your page loads. When the page loads I think the history object is "empty" until you make some push state calls.

Comment: I want my initial url to be www.mysite.com/home and I want to do it in the client side(after the page load).what is your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with History.js, but if you were using the History API  you would do a pushState, not a replaceState.

```
history.pushState(state, title, "/home");
```

EDIT:

How about this?

```
history.pushState(state, title, "/");
history.pushState(state, title, "/home");
```

or this:

```
history.pushState(state, title, "/");
history.replaceState(state, title, "/home");
```

Comment: the problem with pushstate() is that www.mysite.com still will be in the history stack.I want my user to enter www.mysite.com, see the url www.mysite.com/home and then when he/she clicks the back button, the browser take the user where he/she was before www.mysite.com

Comment: @user2078785 Have you confirmed that to be true? I don't think that's the case. It's been awhile since I've worked on this but I am pretty certain you come onto a page with the history having zero entires. I am going to try this in a fiddle.

Comment: actually yes.I go to www.mysite.com(which is currently local), I push a state, I hit the back button and I am still in my own website

Comment: @user2078785 Hey, see my edits. Sorry I'm guessing here but I am not currently on a machine where I can test this stuff myself. And I'm going off what I remember about the API from a couple of months ago.